# How to center an icon vertically when using Bootstrap 3 grid?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having problems with vertical centering an icon at the end of the list item.

[image]

So as you can see i want to vertically centre the right arrow.

I'm using Bootstrap 3, Angular-UI bootstrap JS and ofc AngularJS.

My current code is:

```
<style>
.center {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: none;
}
</style>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-10">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-10">{{ dn.Var1 }}</div>
            <div class="col-xs-3">{{ dn.Var2 }}</div>
            <div class="col-xs-7">{{ dn.Var3 }}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2 center">
        <div class="row">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right "></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: try line-height: 100px 
(insert height of the row here)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
<div class="col-xs-2"> 
   <div class="row" > 
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right col-xs-offset-5" style="padding-top: 50%">
   </span> 
 </div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is not giving any results.

Comment: u need to add `padding-top` for your arrow span class.

Comment: Thanks man :) If you can update your answer to: <div class="col-xs-2">
                <div class="row" >
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right col-xs-offset-5" style="padding-top: 25%"></span>
                </div>
            </div> 
This is producing the result i was looking for. I'll mark it as an answer when you update.